# Classic ASP legacy system returning 0 for all integers from MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

We are handling a move of system for a company and at the same time upgrading their MySQL database from 5.1 to 8.0 and have come across a strange issue whereby all integer fields are now being returned as 0 instead of the value held in the database. The code was all written 10 years ago by another company who used Classic ASP.

Connection string showing used provider/connector:

```
'objConn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}; Server=XXXX; Database=XXXX; UID=xxxxxx; PWD=xxxxxx; charset=UTF8;"'
```

Below is the code used to run the stored procedure:

```
dim objGetFromUsernamePassword, ObjRsLogin
Set objGetFromUsernamePassword = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With objGetFromUsernamePassword
        .ActiveConnection = objConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "sp_LoginUsernamePassword"   
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("$strUserName", adVarChar, adParamInput,256, strUserName)   
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("$strPassword", adVarChar, adParamInput,20, strPassword)                                                        
    Set ObjRsLogin = objGetFromUsernamePassword.Execute         
end with            
set objGetFromUsernamePassword = nothing


if ObjRsLogin.EOF then
Set objRsLogin = nothing
response.write "no records"

response.redirect "login.asp?strLogin=fail"
end if

response.write CLng(ObjRsLogin.fields.Item(0).value)
response.write "-"

For Each fld In ObjRsLogin.Fields
    msg = msg & fld.Name  & "|"
    msg = msg & fld.Value & "|"
    msg = msg & fld.Type  & "|"
Next

response.write msg
```

The resulting output of this code above on the web page is as follows. Apologies if it is a little hard to follow but it should be returning the column name | value and also includes the number that refers to the type also:

> 0-pkLoginID|0|3|strLoginName|testlogin@allinproperty.co.uk|200|strPassword|97bd19e019838ed960a7e9b21ac7d0f0dccc0958|200|strUserName|testlogin|200|strSessionID|1053793318|200|fkLoginTypeID|0|3|fkParentID|0|3|fkDepartmentID|0|3|strEmail|testlogin@allinproperty.co.uk|200|txtNotePad||201|fkUserLevelID|0|3|isActive|0|16|fkContractorID||3|tb_test|0|3|

When the stored procedure is run manually on the database using MySQL Workbench we see the results we expect as you can see below.

[image]

We are using the MySQL ODBC 8.0 connector and are running the code on a 64 bit windows server 2012 virtual machine.

I am currently at a bit of a loss to explain what is happening here.

EDIT TO EXPLAIN WHY THE COMMENTS OF DUPLICATE QUESTION DO NOT ANSWER THIS

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_LoginUsernamePassword`($strUserName varchar(256), $strPassword varchar(20))
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SELECT * From tb_login WHERE (strLoginName = $strUserName ) and (strPassword = sha1($strPassword));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Image of table design to show simple integer columns that should be returned as part of the stored procedure call

[image]

Comment: This might be relevant - [Result is always zero](//stackoverflow.com/q/55714588) but as we don't know what the stored procedure is returning we can only guess.

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question but thanks. I am trying to return simple integers and it is always returning a 0 instead of the actual values. That question shows he is trying to access a value larger than what his standard int will allow so he has to change to a big int. I will edit the question to include the stored procedure as well as the table design

Comment: I would be surprised if it's not a similar issue, probably with the provider.

Comment: I have previously tried converting to strings and big ints but the value is just 0 and cannot be converted to anything because the value simply does not arrive in the vbscript code to do anything with it. It is just 0. If it is an issue with the provider then of course I need to know what this is and if there is a different provider I should be using. Hence asking the question on here. The linked question does not seem to address this issue at all.

Comment: Try using the Unicode driver rather than the ANSI driver, the MySQL 8.0 ANSI driver caused me all sorts of issues.

Comment: yes I have tried that. Still 0. Int(11) is a simple 4 byte integer. The 11 only dictates the display width. Not the value held in it. The value of the first column as you can see from my images is 513. Not in any way close to a big int.

Comment: @Adam Thanks. I have tried this already but sadly it did not have any effect

Comment: Rather than using a connection string try setting up a System DSN in `ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)` and replace the connection string with `DSN=your_system_dsn_name`. There's a lot of options available in the MySQL ODBC configuration. Under `metadata` for example, there's an option to `Treat BIGINT columns as INT columns`, which could be the key.

Comment: @Adam Thanks buddy. We have created a System DSN and tried that too. I will check the BIGINT columns as INT columns and see if that works. The strange thing is that we have another application also in classic ASP and looking at a different schema in the same database that is working.

Comment: Are the tables in the other schema using the same engine as the table that's returning 0? Maybe switching from myisam to innodb or vice-versa could be the fix. But it does seem to be a very strange issue regardless... One other suggestion might be to try the MariaDB ODBC connector, it's compatible with MySQL and it solved an issue I had with retrieving and displaying emojis stored in MySQL. The MySQL 8.0 ODBC connector does seem to have quite a few bugs when used with VBscript from my experience.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I will give that a go after trying the biging to int checkbox. Just logging onto the machine now.

Comment: @Adam Hi Adam. Tried the 64bit DSN but this causes the code to break. The application is 32 bit. Tried the 32 bit DSN with the BigInt to Int checked and that still did not work. I will try the other suggestions you made.

Comment: @Adam checked the engine and both using InnoDB

Comment: You may need to restart MySQL (and/or IIS) when you make changes in the ODBC configuration.

Comment: @Adam Ok will do both each time. I have just dropped the database and am running the sql dump to rebuild it. Previously I had created the db and then run the dump so maybe something I did when creating the db caused the issue. I will keep plugging away. Appreciate the input.

Comment: @Adam I have now tried everything. One database works fine. The other does not. Exactly the same configuration of DSN for each. Both taken as backups (dumps) from the same MySQL server. Character sets and collations all updated on non working database to match the working one. If I use the DSN for the working database then the code works fine indicating some kind of issue with the non working database itself and not connector or code related. I am at a total loss to explain it.

Comment: @CSharpened Hopefully someone else will be able to shed some light, because I really can't think of anything else to suggest. If everything points to it being a database issue then I'd be inclined to remove MySQL and do a fresh install, and maybe even revert back to MySQL 5.7, but I'd hold off on doing something like that, someone might be able to offer a solution yet. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, I feel your pain though, I really do. Best of luck finding a solution :)

Comment: You shouldn't put your actual database login credentials in a question!  Perhaps an Admin can edit the text in a way that the original doesn't show in the edit history?

Comment: I have removed it. Although being that there is no ip or domain name it would be extremely difficult for anyone to know where the database is. It is also sat behind numerous firewalls etc so it can only be access internally.

Answer (score 3):

I confirmed the same issue in my database. I tried changing the INT dataType to DOUBLE and the issue went away (thus confirming the issue only affects INT dataTypes) I then took my database, created a copy and started deleting other columns into the problem disappeared. I discovered that when a column that is part of the query has a datatype of LONGTEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, TEXT, TINYTEXT, JSON or BLOB, it causes the INT columns to be 0, regardless of the value stored in the database. I have filed a bug report with MySQL (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97191) that shows an example of how I was able to reproduce the issue on my system (Server 2019/IIS 10) using MySQL 8.0.17, ODBC Driver 8.0.17 (i tested it with 5.3.13 both 32-bit & 64-bit with same result) and Classic ASP/VBScript.

From what I can tell, in order to get the INT values to display correctly when using a prepared statement from Classic ASP is to exclude any of the TEXT/BLOB/JSON dataTypes from the query.

I would say this is a significant bug...

Comment: Bug still present in MySQL 8.0.18. Going by the bug report it should be fixed in 8.0,19

Answer (score 0):

For us the change to MariaDB Driver was ok. It solved all.
It looks like something is missing in the original driver.

Comment: What version number are you using; and is it 32 or 64-bit? (Thank you.)